# How to use boost.spirit.qi parse string value to attrubute with attribute has default value

Tags: string, parsing, attributes, default

I have a question for boost.spirit.qi string parser. When I want parse string value to std::string attribute, like bellow:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_utree.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/assert.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>   

template <typename P, typename T>
void test_phrase_parser_attr(
    char const* input, P const& p, T& attr, bool full_match = true)
{
    using boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse;
    using boost::spirit::qi::ascii::space;

    char const* f(input);
    char const* l(f + strlen(f));
    if (phrase_parse(f, l, p, space, attr) && (!full_match || (f == l)))
        std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "fail" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str("abc");
    test_phrase_parser_attr("cba", string("cba"), str);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output:abccba

But I want the program output "cba", How can I do?

Comment: I track code to assign_to_attribute_from_iterators struct in assign_to.hpp, it static member function "call" have "traits::is_empty(attr)" decision. It push_back the parse result to std::string when std::string is not empty. I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your str was initialized with "abc". Parser does not clear the string, just appends its output.
Pass in an empty string and you will get back what you want.